# pointing the particular error location in form upon submitting a form using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I created a form in that i am validating the from fields.every thing is working fine but, when I am curating(submitting) the form if any error is there in that form i have point out that place..how to to point out the particular error place.can you please guide me..for me in that form nearly 30 fields is there and the curated button is at last. when the error is top i want to show the error pointing place.

```js
function curate(saveOnly) {
  
  if(isValidForm()){
   var newFormData = JSON.stringify($("#form").serializeArray());
   
    if(saveOnly){
     saveForm(true);
    }else{
     adpart.content.isCurated = true;
     adpart.content.stateVal = $("#curfut").val();
     autoSaveDiagram();
     saveForm();
    }
     
    $(".reveal-overlay").css("display", "none");
    confirmExit();
  }else{
   if(saveOnly){
    toastr.warning('Please fill the mandatory fields to curate', 'Curation Failed!');
   }
  }
 }


function isValidForm() {
  var isValid = checkIfValidText("type") & 
       checkIfValidText("accountname") & 
       checkIfValidText("serviceline") & 
       checkIfValidText("vsmphase")& 
       checkIfValidText("georegion")& 
       checkIfValidText("curfut");
}
return isValid;
}
function checkIfValidTextField(fieldId){
  var isValid = true;  
  if($(fieldId).val().length==0){
   $(fieldId).css('boxShadow',"rgb(255, 0, 0) 0px 0px 10px");
   isValid = false;
  }else{
   $(fieldId).css('boxShadow',"none");
  }
  return isValid;
 }
```

```html
<form action="editor/checklist" method="GET" model="curatorCheckList"
  enctype="text/plain" id="form" name="curatorCheckListForm">
    
    
        <table style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 20px;" class="curator_id">
      <tr>
      <td>
          <div>
          
       Vertical Name
       
       <select name="verticalName" class="Curator-verticalname" id="type" onchange="populateSvcLineAndActName()">
       
         <option value="">Select</option>
         
         <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
         
         <option value="BFS">BFS</option>
         
         <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
         
         <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
         
         <option value="Life Sciences">Life Sciences</option>
         
         <option value="IME">IME</option>
         
         <option value="P & R">P&R</option>
         
         <option value="Banking & Lending">Banking and Lending</option>
         
         <option value="F&A">F&A</option>
        
        </select> 
        
        <span id="acnterrname" style="margin-top: 29px; margin-left: 275px; color: red;"></span>
        
       </div>
        </td>
       
        <td>Account Name
               <select id="accountname" name= "accountName" style=" margin-left: 23px; width: 270px;height: 27px;">
               
                      <option value= ""  selected="selected"></option>
                      
               </select> 
            <span id="acnterrname" style="margin-top: 29px; margin-left: 275px; color: red;"></span>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>Service Line
    
        <select id="serviceline" name="serviceLine" id="serviceline" class="Curator-serviceline" onchange="populateSubserviceLine()" required >
        
       <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
       
     </select> 
     <span id="acnterrname" style="margin-top: 29px; margin-left: 275px; color: red;"></span>
     
    </td>

    <td style="vertical-align: sub; padding-top: 12px;">VSM Phase
     
          <select name="vsmPhase" class="curator-vsmphase" id="vsmphase">
          
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       
         </select> 
         <span id="acnterrname" style="margin-top: 29px; /*  margin-left: 275px; */ color: red;"></span>
                      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    
                     VSM Date
                     <input type="date"
      name="completionDate" id="date" value="" class="curator-date"  onkeydown="return false;"> <span id="acnterrname"
      style="color: red; margin-top: 29px;"></span>
      </td>

  </tr>
      <tr id="subserviceline">

     <td>
             Which Sub service Line does this VSM belong to ?
     </td>

     <td>
       <select id="subservice" name="subservice" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px;">
       <!-- <option value="">select</option> -->
          </select> 
          <span id="acnterrname" style="color: red; margin-top: 29px;"></span>
     </td>
   </tr>

      <tr>
      <td> 
           Which Geo/Region does this VSM belongs to?
      </td>
      
      <td>
           <select name="geo" id="georegion" class="curator_selectbox">
           
       <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
       
       <option value="Global/Multi-Region">Global/multi-Region</option>
       
       <option value="North America">North America</option>
       
       <option value="Latin America">Latin America</option>
       
       <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
       
       <option value="Middle East & Africa">Middle East & Africa</option>
       
       <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
       
       <option value="Australia & New Zealand">Australia & New Zealand</option>
       
        </select>
        <span id="adpartfiles" style="margin-top: 29px; margin-left: 275px; color: red;"></span>
        </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
    <td>
          IS this VSM the current State or future state VSM?
    </td>
    
    <td>
         <select name="curfut" id="curfut" class="curator_selectbox">
         
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="Current">Current</option>
       <option value="Future"">Future</option>
       
      </select> 
      <span id="adpartfiles" style="margin-top: 29px; margin-left: 275px; color: red;"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
   <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 10px !important; vertical-align: sub;">
      
      <div id="curator"></div>
      VSM Name(Vertical,Service Line, Sub service Line, Name)
      
      </td>
      
      <td>
      
           <input type="text" name="vsmName" id="vsmName" class="curator-textbox" value="" readonly /><br>
          
           <textarea  name="append" id="append" readonly
       style="border: 1px solid #5db961; margin-top: 15px; background-color: #d0f7d2; resize: none; width: 379px; height: 35px; maxlength="100">
       
        </textarea>
     
     <span id="acnterrname" style="margin-top: 29px; margin-left: 275px; color: red;"></span>
     </td>
     </tr>
</table>


<input 
                style="margin-left: 135px; width: 100px; height: 36px; cursor: pointer;"
             type="button" class="button margin-zero create-new-dialog-btn"
             value="Curate" id="curateId" onClick="curate(false)">
                    
                    
                    
                    </form>
```

Comment: you can show error message or you can use focus method to focus that field.

Comment: I want to focus that field position.if any error is there it will scroll to that position

Comment: So call `.focus()` on the field.

Comment: how can you help me. how to do

Comment: but if you have multiple errors , instead of focus use error message

Comment: document.getElementById("id").focus(); use id of input field containing error.

Comment: iam showing error messages also...actually i have to show the position of first error postion. when  i click curate button..if it is clear it will show the next position of error

Comment: ok then use document.getElementById("id").focus() metnod.

Comment: can you see my code and where i have to add that focus method

Comment: you can add focus method in checkIfValidTextField() method when your validation fails.

Comment: yaa its working...thank you so much..@santosh gore

Answer (score 0):

You have several erros in your code.

Firstly, `checkIfValidText` function is not defined. It is defined as `checkIfValidTextFiedld`.

Secondly, you are using `$(fieldId).val()`  this will translate to an error as id is referenced with a `#`. Use `$('#'+fieldId).val()`.

I have used `.on()` click function in my fiddle code because the `curate()` function was not able to load before the DOM and it was not able to find the `curate()` function. Use the `on()` click listener if you face similar issue.

Hope it helps.

[JS fiddle for working code](https://jsfiddle.net/ujkpv89c/)